# handlebars views displaying prior date of mongoDB date - using date-fns format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date-fns, handlebarshelper

**mongoDB collection has the date field I'm trying to display on my form as:**

```
    issueDate: 2020-10-09T00:00:00.000Z
```

**My handlebars view is only attempting to display the formatted date**...like so:

```
</div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date Added</label>
            <input type="date" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    name="issueDate" 
                    placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" 
                    value="{{formatDate document.issueDate}}">
            <div class="text-danger">
                {{document.issueDate}}
            </div>
    </div>
```

**I'm sending this mongoDBDate to my handlebars helper formatDate**:

```
    Thu Oct 08 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

My **formatDate handlebars.helper code is:**

```
    hbs.handlebars.registerHelper("formatDate", function(mongoDBDate) {
    if (!mongoDBDate == "") {
        var displayDate = format(new Date(mongoDBDate), "yyyy-MM-dd", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});    
        return displayDate
        }
    else {
        return mongoDBDate;
        }
    })
```

But regardless of what date is in mongoDB or passed to the helper...the helper appears to receive the date of the day before. I see nothing that could be doing this. I suspected it's a timezone issue (mongoDB storing dates in GMT)...but I have tried a number of things to no avail.

Any suggestions welcome!